# Scrolling parent of display:grid unexpectedly scrolls when a child's grid-row-start changes

Tags: html, css, scroll, css-grid

We have a list with cells that have explicit grid-rows/columns set inside a grid which is inside a scrollable element. We draw a selection border over a number of these cells.

When the scrolling element is *not* scrolled all the way to the top, changing the selection element's grid-row-start causes the scrolling area to scroll to the point where the offset of the top of the selection element in relation to the viewport is maintained. In other words, if the selection element is 100px from the top of the viewport, and you click on a cell lower down on the page, the scroll element will scroll down until the selection element is 100px from the top of the viewport again.

This *usually* happens. Sometimes it doesn't on a fresh page. But click on the scrollbar and scrolling a teeny bit causes this behavior to start happening again. This leads me to believe this is a browser bug and not intended behavior, but it repros in Chrome, Edge, AND FireFox.

You can even open the F12 tools and modify grid-row-start manually, and the scrolling behavior occurs.

Sample code is below. I've found a workaround, which is commented out, but it is not ideal. To replicate the "bug", scroll down a bit then start clicking on cells.

Is this intended behavior? What's causing it? Any easy way to avoid it?

Thanks!

```js
window.onload = () => {
  const list = document.getElementById('list');

  const numRows = 100;
  const numColumns = 8;

  for (let i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
    let row = document.createElement('div');
    row.className = 'row';
    row.style.gridRow = String(i + 1);
    for (let j = 0; j < numColumns; j++) {
      let cell = document.createElement('div');
      cell.className = 'cell';
      cell.style.gridRow = String(i + 1);
      cell.style.gridColumn = String(j + 1);
      cell.innerText = `${i} - ${j}`;
      cell.onclick = () => {
        const selection = document.getElementById('selection');
        selection.style.gridArea = `${i+1} / ${j+1} / ${i+2} / ${j+2}`;
        /*
        selection.style.display = 'none';
        setTimeout(() => {
            document.getElementById('selection').style.display = '';    
        }, 0);
        */
      };
      row.appendChild(cell);
    }
    list.appendChild(row);
  }
};
```

```css
.list {
  display: grid;
}

.row {
  display: contents;
}

.cell {
  outline: 1px solid black;
  padding: 12px 4px;
}

.selection {
  outline: 5px solid green;
  grid-area: 20 / 4 / 21 / 5;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='list' id='list'>
  <div class='selection' id='selection'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using the same ID value for multiple elements loaded to the DOM?

Comment: No. You can see in the minimal repro code I posted. Our actual code does not use IDs, we maintain refs to specific elements, so we will never run into issues with multiple elements with the same ID.

Comment: Not sure the problem is being reproduced. Testing in Chrome. https://jsfiddle.net/pcsxted7/

Comment: I am able to reproduce the issue in jsfiddle. Did you scroll down a bit? It didn't initially repro in codepen due to the element that was scrolling, I had to modify the body's styles to make it scroll to get the bug to appear. But it happens without any changes in your jsfiddle.

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin try clicking on the arrows in the scrollbar. The bug does not happen very often with your jsfiddle, but clicking the arrows seems to be the most reliable way to get it to trigger, oddly.